# Sequence of random variables is exchangeable iff every subsequence is equivalently distributed

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm trying to prove (or find a reference for) the following result:

> Let $E$ be a Polish space. A family $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of $E$-valued random variables is exchangeable if and only if for every choice of natural numbers $1 \leq n_1 < n_2 < \ldots$, we have $(X_1, X_2, \ldots) \stackrel{\mbox{$\mathcal{D}$}}{=} (X_{n_1}, X_{n_2}, \ldots)$, where $\stackrel{\mbox{$\mathcal{D}$}}{=}$ denotes equivalence in distribution.

A family of random variables as above is exchangeable if and only if given any finite permutation $\varrho : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, the stochastic processes $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ and $(X_{\varrho(n)})_{n \geq 1}$ are equivalently distributed.

I'm having trouble proving "if". I'm not sure how to extract a finite permutation from a choice of subsequences, so I'm guessing instead I'll have to use de Finetti's theorem. This requires me to find a random measure $\Xi$ for which, given $\Xi$, we have that $X_1$ (or any other $X_n$) is $\Xi$-distributed.

One strategy would be to construct a suitable tight collection of measures $\left(\tilde\mu_i\right)_{i \in I} \subseteq \mathcal M_1\left(\mathcal M_1(E)\right)$, apply Prohorov's theorem to find a weak limit $\tilde\mu$, and choose a random variable $\Xi$ with values in $\mathcal M_1(E)$ so that $\mathbb P_\Xi = \tilde\mu$. This is one way that de Finetti's representation theorem can be proven; in this proof, the tight collection of measures is $\tilde{\mathcal F} := \left(\mathbb P_{\xi_n(X)}\right)_{n \geq 1}$, where given $x \in E^{\mathbb N}$ (note $X = (X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is an $E^\mathbb N$-valued random variable), $\xi_n(x)$ is the empirical distribution $\xi_n(x) = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}$. Proving that $\tilde{\mathcal F}$ is tight doesn't rely on exchangeability of $X$, so we have the weak limit point $\tilde\mu \in \mathcal M_1(\mathcal M_1(E)$ of $\tilde{\mathcal F}$, and a $\mathcal M_1(E)$-valued random variable $\Xi$ so that $\tilde\mu = \mathbb P_{\Xi}$.

But in the proof of de Finetti's theorem that I'm trying to adapt, they show $\mathbb P_{(X_1, \ldots, X_k)} = \mathbb P_{\Xi^{\otimes k}}$ (and thus $X_1$ is $\Xi$-distributed given $\Xi$) by showing that given $f_1, \ldots, f_k \in C_b(E)$, letting $F(x) = f_1(x_1) \cdots f_k(x_k)$,
$$
\mathbb E\left[F(X) \right] = \lim_{i \to \infty} \mathbb E\left[\int f_1 \,d\xi_{n_i}(X) \cdots \int f_k\,d\xi_{n_i}(X)\right] = \mathbb E\left[\int F\,d\Xi^{\otimes k}\right] 
$$
which does require exchangeability of $X$ (specifically the first limit equality above). So my goal is to prove something similar to this limit assuming $(X_1, X_2, \ldots) \stackrel{\mbox{$\mathcal{D}$}}{=} (X_{n_1}, X_{n_2}, \ldots)$ for any subsequence.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to go about this? I'd accept a reference as well as an answer.

**Addendum:** The proof of de Finetti's theorem that I was trying to adapt is in Section 13.4 of Achim Klenke's *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*.

Comment: Finite permutation means $\rho(k) = k$ for all but finitely many $k$?

Comment: @PeterMorfe yes, that’s correct: a bijection $\varrho : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ that fixes all but finitely many $k \in \mathbb N$.